# How to update python version on choregraphe

Tags: python, ibm-watson, pepper, choregraphe

I want to update python version on choregraphe from "2.7.2" to "2.7.10" or something newer (I use MacBook Pro).
Now, I'm trying to use Watson Web API, and have SSLEroor.

I think it's caused by python version, so I confirmed it on choregraphe then it is "2.7.2", also I confirmed Watson API can work on python 2.7.10 environment so I think it's about choregraphe environment problem not about codes.

```
SSLError(1, '_ssl.c503: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with Choregraphe.
You should consider developing directly in Python.